# Remove the "amp;" from the URL

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I use this Jquery:

```
  $('.FilteredData').change(function () {
            var link = $(this).is(":checked") ? "@Url.Action("DataBlacklist", new { fw=12,id="test" })" : "";
            window.open( link , "_self");
        });
```

and the URL result is : `http://localhost:49173/Operasional/DPWD/DataBlacklist?fw=12&amp;id=tes`

I want the result like this : `http://localhost:49173/Operasional/DPWD/DataBlacklist?fw=12&id=tes`

I want remove the "amp;"

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do a string replace:

```
  $('.FilteredData').change(function () {
            var link = $(this).is(":checked") ? "@Url.Action("DataBlacklist", new { fw=12,id="test" })" : "";
            link = link.toString().replace('amp','');
            window.open( link , "_self");
        });
```